# Python xlwt - making a column readonly (cell protect)

Tags: python, excel, overriding, protected, xlwt

Is there a way to make a particular cell read-only/write protected in python xlwt?

I know there's is a cell_overwrite_ok flag which does not allow to overwrite contents of cells (all cells) but can this be done on cell by cell basis.

Thanks,
Sun

Answer (score 9):

Excel cells have a **locked** attribute that is enabled by default. However, this attribute is only invoked when the worksheet's **protection** attribute is also set to `True`. If the worksheet is not protected, the **locked** attribute is ignored.

Therefore, your question isn't best framed as *how to make cells read-only*. Rather, the question is *how to make cells editable after protecting the worksheet*.

...Here you are:

```
from xlwt import Workbook, Worksheet, easyxf

# ...

# Protect worksheet - all cells will be read-only by default
my_worksheet.protect = True  # defaults to False
my_worksheet.password = "something_difficult_to_guess"

# Create cell styles for both read-only and editable cells
editable = easyxf("protection: cell_locked false;")
read_only = easyxf("")  # "cell_locked true" is default

# Apply your new styles when writing cells
my_worksheet.write(0, 0, "Can't touch this!", read_only)
my_worksheet.write(2, 2, "Erase me :)", editable)

# ...
```

The cell styles (`easyxf` class) are also useful for declaring background color, font weight, etc.

Cheers.

Comment: What if I have to password protect the entire excel file?

Comment: Actually, I've to store a spark dataframe in a excel file format with few column as a read only nature? Can you guide me regarding the same?