# Python xlsx cell protection (lock)

Tags: python, excel

I need to export a list to excel with some cells or columns protected (read only).

The problem is that i use openpyxl python module to write to xlsx, but i think only xlwt has cell protection feature. And xlwt seems to not support xlsx.

Anyone has found a workaround?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526296/python-xlwt-making-a-column-readonly-cell-protect

Comment: @ColinO'Coal i know xlwt has support for that, but doesn't save xlsx format, only xls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python module [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html) allows you to write XLSX files and add worksheet cell protection (among other things):

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('protection.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create a cell format with protection properties.
unlocked = workbook.add_format({'locked': False})

# Format the columns to make the text clearer.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 40)

# Turn worksheet protection on.
worksheet.protect()

# Write a locked and unlocked cell.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Cell B1 is locked. It cannot be edited.')
worksheet.write('A2', 'Cell B2 is unlocked. It can be edited.')

worksheet.write_formula('B1', '=1+2')  # Locked by default.
worksheet.write_formula('B2', '=1+2', unlocked)

workbook.close()
```

See the [protect()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-protect) section of the docs for full details.

[image: Cell Protection Example]

Comment: Great, i didn't found this project! I will try your module. Thanks