# Python: how to read the data from the oracle, and then write to Excel

Tags: python, excel, oracle

Python: how to read the data from the oracle, and then write to Excel, Excel part of the column can be read only?

Answer (score 1):

Install [database driver](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/5.3/index.html) for connecting to the db and [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to streamline the excel writing and data manipulations.

`$ pip install cx_Oracle pandas`

in your script do something like this:

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/password@dsn')

data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM mytable', con)
con.close()

data.head() # take a peek at data
data.to_excel('my_oracle_table.xlsx')
```

Comment: I got it what you have showed,but I don't know how to set Excel part of the column can be read only.( I use python2 and xlrd,xlwt)

Comment: You want to make ony some columns read only, or the whole worksheet?

Comment: I want to make ony some columns read only, but not the whole worksheet.

Comment: I would be curious about the solution as well. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

this answer is come from:
[Python xlwt - making a column readonly (cell protect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526296/python-xlwt-making-a-column-readonly-cell-protect)

```
from xlwt import Workbook, Worksheet, easyxf
# ...
# Protect worksheet - all cells will be read-only by default
my_worksheet.protect = True  # defaults to False
my_worksheet.password = "something_difficult_to_guess"

# Create cell styles for both read-only and editable cells
editable = easyxf("protection: cell_locked false;")
read_only = easyxf("")  # "cell_locked true" is default
# Apply your new styles when writing cells
my_worksheet.write(0, 0, "Can't touch this!", read_only)
my_worksheet.write(2, 2, "Erase me :)", editable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Robin Nemeth for his answer. I made a little modification to it and got the required output.

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/password@dsn')
data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM mytable', con)
data.to_excel('my_oracle_table.xlsx')  #called before closing the connection
con.close()
```

Here, data.to_excel() should be called before closing the connection, else will result in the following error "DatabaseError: DPI-1040: LOB was already closed".

Even removed the data.head() function, which didn't affect my output.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cx_Oracle

import pandas as pd

import xlsxwriter

con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/password@IP:port/service_name')

with pd.ExcelWriter("", engine="xlsxwriter", options = {'strings_to_numbers': True, 'strings_to_formulas': False}) as writer:

                try:

                    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM myTABLE", con)

                    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Sheet1", header = True, index = False)

                    print("File saved successfully!")

                    row = len(df.axes[0])

                except:

                    print("There is an error")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).